# homework : torsors of constraints: Coulomb's laws

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, civil-engineering, statics, fluid

[image][image]Bonjour , j’ai un devoir maison sur les torseurs mécaniques en lien avec la loi de Coulomb et Statiquecet je n’arrive pas à résoudre! Pouvez-vous m’aider s’il vous plaît?! Je met le sujet en photo juste en bas , merci[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovaST.jpg)

Comment: Si vous le traduisez en Anglais il y a plus de chance, si non ca sera fermer assez vite..

Comment: Je sais merci de me l’avoir rappelé mais  je ne parle pas très bien l’anglais et la traduction ne donne pas les bonnes significations des termes utilisés :( c’est pour ça que j’ai mis en français….. merci quand même et bonne soirée.